# Zoom in and zoom out fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to smoothly zoom in fragment to full screen when it comes and smoothly zoom out and fits into its actual position when exits how can I do that

Thanks!

for smooth zoom in, when replacing fragment:

```
 ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, 0 + "_image");

    viewPagerFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
                viewPagerFragment.setEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
                viewPagerFragment.setReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());
                viewPagerFragment.setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);
                viewPagerFragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
                //listener.subCategoryItemClick(new ProductDetailFragment());
                postponeEnterTransition();


   getParentFragment().getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment, viewPagerFragment)
                       // .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in, R.anim.zoom_out)
                        .addSharedElement(imageView, "productImage")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

but fragment coming and leaving with glitch

Comment: Do you have an example of an existing application or video or anything to better illustrate what kind of animation we are talking about here?

Comment: I dnt have video but im following ASOS, in product detail when user clicks on viewpager on top of product detail the image smoothly expands to full screen and smoothly goes back to its actual position when closed

Comment: Ok I get what you need :) 
Its basically the Android Transition API. You have the whole project with example code here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic

Comment: I have already applied it :) its coming with glitch not smoothly

Comment: I would need to see your code to help you more. 

Try to a) record a video in android studio and upload to youtube and share a public link so we see how to app is miss behaving and b) post your fragment class code and xml , activity calling code and xml because I have an idea what you wrote wrong but I would like to be sure.

Comment: the architecture is complex, let me explain then i will upload code, if you have seen product detail, for viewpager on the top of product detail, i have used fragmentpageradapter which returns a fragment when click on fragment it opens up other viewpager thats using fragmentpageradapter

Comment: something like this? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html

Comment: right now im facing glitches in shared element transition

Comment: Describe the "glitch" please :)

Comment: like blink when transition happening :) not smooth w

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169167/discussion-between-bko-and-blackhawk).